# Prove the language L of all palindromes over {0,1} is in NP

Tags: complexity-theory, context-free

Wouldn't this language be in P, since it is a context free language. And every context free language is a member of P? Or would it be otherwise?

Comment: If it is in P, does it tell you anything about being NP?

Comment: @Evil Do you mean P=NP?

Comment: I suggest reviewing the definitions of P and NP. You can consult our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard).